# Two columns and background complication

Tags: jquery, css

I need to interface with the side column (reminders, etc.) and a central column where the content for each page.

I have two columns will be equal to their level and that I can do. The problem right column consists of three sections for the wallpaper. Has the top and bottom that have a fixed height. The middle part varies in height according to content in it.

My problem is that I need the middle section will match the height to that eventually all will be equal height column the second column.

I tried to do it with a script. The problem, when I use the jquery animate function column does not add height Banmtzih then created a small jump.

There is a way to do this?

My Code:

```
<div class="main_content">
    <div id="area_right">
        <div id="area_right_top">
            <div id="area_right_bottom">
                <div id="area_right_content">
                    My content..
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div>

    <div id="area_left">
        <div id="area_left_top">
            <div id="area_left_bottom">
                 <div id="area_left_content">
                    My left content
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Preview: [Preview](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/18298179/ps.jpg)

Thanks!

Comment: please post your jquery code also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use an other hierarchical embodiment of your division as here below, to use **css** style sheets and to use [this trick](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/).

```
<div class="main_content">
    <div id="area_right">
        <div class="wrarper">
            <!-- 100% height and margin-bottom -XXXpx throught CSS-->
            <div id="area_right_top"><!-- determined height throught CSS-->
            </div>
                    My content..
            <div class="push"></div><!-- height:XXXpx throught CSS-->
        </div>
        <div id="area_right_bottom"><!-- height:XXXpx throught CSS-->
        </div>
    <div>
    ect ect     
</div>
```

You may want to search "CSS sticky footer" in a search engine.

Answer (score 0):

There is actualy a trick to achieve this without any js, wich is always a plus in my opinion. I'll try to explain:

- slice the entire image you provided up into 3 pieces, the fixed top and bottom parts, and a 1 pixel high middle part you can repeat.
- structure your html as follows:

```
​<div id="page-wrap"/>
    <div id="top-bg"></div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="left">
            ...
        </div>
        <div id="right">
            ...
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;"><!-- clearfix --></div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom-bg"></div>     
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

- next you apply the background images to top-bg, and bottom-bg as no-repeat images and set there dimensions fixed
- you apply the center image to the content div and set it to repeat along the y axis
- float your right and left columns and give them a negative margin top and bottom to make them flow over the top and bottom div

This should do the trick. Now no matter which get the biggest, left or right, the entire content will stretch. And by setting the background to the wrapper, the smallest column will appear to stretch along, although it will only take up as much height as it requires.

I know this is a bit difficult to understand from my lowsy explaination, so i set up a small example for you to clarify: http://jsfiddle.net/jczXV/